# Swing not drawing on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swing, paintcomponent

I am trying to draw an incredibly basic shape using swing in Java, however for some reason it does not seem to be working. This is code that I downloaded from my lecturer that he showed us in a lecture, but when I run it the window opens but nothing is drawn and I have no idea why.

```
package graphicsEx;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Lecture1Example extends JPanel{
    // This is where the JPanel gets (re-)painted when the screen is refreshed.
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Cast to Graphics2D for more features.        
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(20,30,40,50);
        g2D.setColor(Color.red);
        g2D.draw(rect);
        g2D.fill(rect); 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Playing with Graphics");
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setContentPane(new Lecture1Example());        
    }
}
```

I am using the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Try calling super.paintComponent(g)

Comment: Make `frame.setVisible(true)` _last_.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, can't believe it was something as simple as that, thank you so much

Comment: See trashgod's comment; also maybe you want to add your panel to the content pane, instead of replacing the content pane.

Comment: +1 mad and trashgod. also dont call `setSize` on `JFrame` rather override `getPreferredSize()` of `JPanel` and return Dimensions which fit the drawings and call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible. Also use [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) to create and manipulate Swing components via `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX` block.

Answer (score 7):

Dear user1821475's lecturer:

- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- "Subclasses of Swing components which have a UI delegate (vs. direct subclasses of `JComponent`), should invoke [`super.paintComponent()`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks) within their `paintComponent` override.
- "As a convenience `add` and its variants, `remove` and `setLayout` have been overridden to [forward](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) to the `contentPane` as necessary."
- The outermost `Container` should be `setVisible()` only *after* invoking `pack()` and other methods affecting geometry.