# .pack() causes the components to be in the wrong place but works after window resize

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I am creating a game in java using Swing.

I am using

```
mainJFrame.setExtendedState(mainJFrame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

on my JFrame to start it as a maximized window.

After this I am using

```
mainJFrame.pack();
```

to be able to get the correct x & y coordinates of components in the GUI. I need those coordinates since i'm painting custom images to the GUI. So far everything is fine.

When a user has passed a level, i rebuild the GUI to updated it to the new level settings and then i call pack() again.

When calling pack() the components are placed in the wrong place, slightly below where they are supposed to be.

However, manually resizing the window causes the components to go to the right place again.

I have tried calling `mainJFrame.revalidate()` and `mainJFrame.repaint()` after the `pack()` but this gives no effect.

If needed I can supply printscreens and code.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: This is because `pack()` tries to shrink your objects to a minimum size. Try using setPreferredSize instead :)

Comment: @Pphoenix See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson My questions is, what can be done to stop the components to be placed in the wrong place? Working on posting an MCVE.

Comment: @Chrippe what I am thinking is, its not `pack()`. The problem is in your layout. So as Andrew suggested, post an MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually resizing the window validates the enclosing container and all of its subcomponents. To avoid the effect you describe, call `setVisible()` only *after* you have added components and invoked `pack()`. More related suggestions may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265540/230513). If the problem persists, please edit your question to include an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Setting setVisible(false) before calling pack() fixed this. :)

Comment: Also consider looking for an errant `setVisible(true)` earlier in execution order.